# accessing a service which is hosted on the intranet

Tags: dialogflow-es

Hi I am new to Dialogflow. I am trying to do the following
I am trying to create a simple bot application which would use a webhook to connect to an external service (hosted on my local webserver/ company server). 
Based on the documentation [Docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) it seems that the service has to be publicly accessible. Can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the webhook server must be at a publicly accessible HTTPS address.

If you are trying to use an internal server that is not available to the public Internet, you may wish to look into a tunneling service such as [ngrok](http://ngrok.com).